# What size metal gate post for 5’x6’ gate?

Tags: fence, gates, gate-post

Can anyone advise on the right steel post size for a 10’x6’ double gate?

I am building a 10ft wide double gate, (two 5ft wide sections). The gate will be 6ft tall and use cedar pickets. Any posts will be sunk 36” deep in concrete. I wanted to use square steel or iron posts, but I am not sure if I should use 3” or 4” posts. Posts would like be schedule 40 steel or 14 gauge since that is what is available in my area.

Comment: 4" seems obvious, unless there's a massive price difference...

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate can you explain (in an answer) what makes 4" obvious? And, is 3" _sufficient_?

Comment: In this case, it's pure intuition, not engineering. These are big gates. 3" might be sufficient, but one could either do the engineering and decide for real, or just skip on past the engineering and get something bigger. I'd still be curious about the price differential, though. Maybe the OP priced these out and could educate us.

Comment: @Aloysius Defenestrate Vendor doing the install wanted to charge ~$400 USD for the upgrade to 4"

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. If you don't mind me asking, is that a large upcharge relative to the total price? And what (if anything) did the vendor say about a 3" vs 4" post?

Comment: About 25% of the total cost for the gate. Vendor said that both are acceptable with this gate width, but for peace of mind, customers often upgrade to the 4"